# Control FLV/MP4 Audio & Pan Levels

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

How can I control the audio & pan levels of an external FLV or MP4 video that I am playing through a Video object?

In AS 2, the way to do this was to create an empty movieclip and then use the attachAudio function, which has been deprecated. Should I go about doing this the same way or is there a better way to control the audio without having to jump through hoops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. There is a much more effective way in AS 3 to adjust sound properties.

```
stream_ns.soundTransform.volume = vol;
stream_ns.soundTransform.pan = panLevel;
```

[ActionScript 3.0 API - NetStream#soundTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/NetStream.html#soundTransform)

Comment: It looks like as of Flash Player 10, the pan functionality is broken: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-2044